# How to write short code of finding random integer based probability?

Tags: python, random, lambda, probability, integer-arithmetic

```
from random import *

dice_roll = int(input("dice throwing count?: "))
even_num_cnt = 0

for i in range(dice_roll):
    num = randint(1,6)
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even_num_cnt += 1

print(even_num_cnt / dice_roll)
```

This is the code of finding the probability of `even_num_cnt` by `dice_roll`.
Is there a simpler code (like a one-line code) using other functions in Python 3?

I tried `lambda`:

```
from random import *

v = []
even_num_cnt = 0
dice_roll = int(input())

for i in range(dice_roll):
    v.append(randint(1,6))
    x = lambda dice_roll: dice_roll % 2 == 0
    if(x):
        even_num_cnt +=1

print(even_num_cnt / dice_roll)
```

like this but it seems like I am not knowing how `lambda`s work properly.

Comment: `Is there a simpler code` - not much simpler than your first attempt.

Comment: You are simulating the probability. It's fine, no need to make it simpler. OTOH, you could *calculate* the probability instead of simulating it, if that is your cup of tea.

Comment: I wonder if I can make that into a one line code that can be called as a function in other parts of code

Comment: `lambda` is just a short-hand way of creating functions (instead of `def`). The functions they define are usually short, but they still need to be **called** in order for the code in the function to be executed. There's no built-in Python function that I know of that does what you're trying to do, unfortunately,

Comment: thanks everyone. I will go with the first one

Comment: you have to run lambda function - `x(somevalue)`

Comment: `even_num_cnt = sum(randint(1, 6) % 2 == 0 for i in range(dice_roll))` - it uses fact that `True` is treated as `1` and `False` as `0` so I can sum `randint(1, 6) % 2 == 0` which gives `True` or `False`

Comment: furas, thanks! sum() seems to be a function worthy to remember